# Double quotation related issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I want to change a table's column name the below query works properly

```
 EXEC sp_rename '[Table].[NAME]', 'FullName', 'COLUMN'
```

But when i want to do it using a varibale it not worked

```
 declare @var nvarchar(max)=''
 select @var=@var+'Exec sp_rename  '[Table].[NAME]',
 'FullName','Column';' from NewTable
  exec(@var)
```

But if i am using double quotation the query works properly

```
  declare @var nvarchar(max)=''
 select @var=@var+'Exec sp_rename  ''[Table].[NAME]'',''FullName'',''Column'';' from NewTable
  exec(@var)
```

why it is necessary to use ' ' here?

Comment: You need to make your Question clear. Are those *variables* or pure *string literals* (inside quotes) ?

Comment: string inside the quotes

Answer (score 1):

It is not the double quotation mark. The second one works since you have a proper inline query for the second one and you are escaping the colon properly for your query.

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)=''
 select @var=@var+'Exec sp_rename  ''[Table].[NAME]'',
 ''FullName'',''Column'';' from NewTable
  exec(@var)
```

Note that `''` is not the same as `"` and **Single quotes are escaped by doubling them up**

To take `'Full Name'` as string in your query with single quotes you have to escpae it using `''` like `''Full Name''` So now in your query it will be treated as `'full name'` rather than `full name`.

If you will not escape it using the single quotes then it will result in `full name` and hence give you an error.

Comment: @mehdilotfi:- You are welcome. Do change your answer else i am afraid you will get some downvotes :(

Comment: yeah i meant to say why it is necessary to use ' ' here?

Comment: @SaNa3819:- I have answered that. You need to escape the single quotes of you query. Hope that makes it clear! :)

Comment: What about ' '[Table].[NAME]' ' instead of ' [Table].[NAME] '

Comment: @SaNa3819:- The reasoning is same. You want to escape the table name with quotes there also. Since the proper query is `EXEC sp_rename '[Table].[NAME]', 'FullName', 'COLUMN'` **NOT** `EXEC sp_rename [Table].[NAME], FullName', 'COLUMN`